# Select rows which match common criterias

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't seem to twist my brain to this, I believe simple, question.

I have the below table (Id and Value together forms the key), the table will be large with millions of entries.

**table**

```
ID      Value
ID_A    VAL_1
ID_A    VAL_2
ID_A    VAL_3
ID_B    VAL_1
ID_B    VAL_2
ID_C    VAL_3
```

I want to get all ids who match an arbitrary selection, it could be:

GIVE ME ALL IDS WHO HAVE `(Value = 'val_1') AND (value = 'val_3')`

This should return `(ID_A)` as its the only id who have both val1 and val3. How do I accomplish this in a performance vice clever manner.

Comment: Based on your sample you cannot return `ID_A` and `ID_B` because only `ID_A` has both `val_1` and `val_3`, is that a mistake?

Comment: Sorry, mistake - my example should only return ID_A / updated question

Comment: @Bluefeet gave you the answer.  It's one I've had to use a lot.  But, it should be noted that this doesn't scale well to large numbers of records.  You will only get scalable performance from pivoting your table back to somethign more traditional `(id, v1, v2, v3, etc)` and then indexing every search combination that you'll ever need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want this, this will give you all id's that have both `VAL_1` and `VAL_3`:

```
select id
from yourtable
where value in ('VAL_1', 'VAL_3')   
group by id
having count(distinct value) > 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c5df/1)

Based on the data you provided only `ID_A` matches because it is the only one with both the `VAL_1` and `VAL_3`

Or you can change this slightly to this:

```
select id
from yourtable
where value in ('VAL_1', 'VAL_3')   
group by id
having count(distinct value) = 2
```

Comment: +1 : Yey, someone who actually read it all, understood it all! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested select statement:

```
SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE Value = 'VAL_1')
AND Value = 'VAL_3';
```

Comment: Yes, you get A, B and C.  But the OP only wants A and B...  so your answer says "this doesn't do what you asked"?

Comment: But in example data I only want ID_A as only this one have both val_1 and val_3. (I updated my question to clearify)

Comment: But this will always return nothing as no row has both a value of VAL_1 AND VAL_3

Comment: It's doing two queries. The nested SELECT is looking for all IDs that have a Value column value of 'VAL_1'. It's then taking those IDs and looking to see if any of them also have a Value column value of 'VAL_3'. If they do, then they are returned in your result.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT id
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE value IN ('val_1', 'val_3')
) t
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Regards

Comment: This is functionally identical to @bluefeets answer.  Except that it's 10 minutes later, and doesn't include a SQL Fiddle Demo...  That makes it slightly redundant?

Comment: Actually it is, I just read bluefeet's answer and it works similar even better than mine.